# Flutter align two items on extremes - one on the left and one on the right

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to align two items at extremes one on the left and one on the right.
I have one row that is aligned to the left and then a child of that row is aligned to the right. However it seems the child row is picking up the alignment property from its parent. This is my code

```
var SettingsRow = new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
                Text("Right",softWrap: true,),
            ],
        );

        var nameRow = new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
                Text("Left"),
                SettingsRow,
            ],
        );
```

as a result I get something like this

```
Left Right
```

What I would like is

```
Left      Right
```

Also there is enough space on the Row. My question is why is the child Row not exhibiting its `MainAxisAlignment.end` property ?

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Use a single `Row` instead, with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.

```
new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    new Text("left"),
    new Text("right")
  ]
);
```

Or you can use `Expanded`

```
new Row(
  children: [
    new Text("left"),
    new Expanded(
      child: settingsRow,
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: On the 2nd example I use his `settingsRow`, which contains `Text("right")`

Comment: I see. Missed that part

Comment: Thanks. But out of curiosity why doesnt my code work ? The `mainAxisAlignment` of the child does not occur. Do the properties of parents overtake those of kids ?

Comment: @MistyD No they don't. But nesting row/columns with a `max` property requires an `Expanded` or else they won't fill the space available.

Comment: 2nd one is very much better.

Comment: I want one widget at the center and other to the extreme right. How can we achieve that ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy If you are not afraid that these two widgets may overlap each other if their sizes are too large, I suggest using Stack and then two children wrapped in Align widgets (one with Alignment.center, other one with Alignment.centerRight). Or, have three Expanded widgets in your row with flex: 1. First will contain blank (SizedBox), second - your centered widget (wrapped in Center) and third containing your right-aligned widget.

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk, Thanks.  I was able to do it using Spacer().

Comment: Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340350/align-items-inside-row-in-flutter

Answer (score 137):

A simple solution would be to use `Spacer()` between the two widgets

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text("left"),
    Spacer(),
    Text("right")
  ]
);
```

Comment: What does Spacer() do ? In a row, i want to keep one widget in the center and another to extreme right. Is this possible using spacer() ?

Comment: My comment might not be relevant to the question, but @Pritish answer is great if you have for instance 4 widgets, and you want 3 of them on the left, and 1 on the right. Adding Spacer() between 3rd and 4th widget does the trick.

Comment: This is really good since it allows me to do it with more than 2 widgets

Comment: how can we do it when using `Wrap`?

Comment: This one worked nicely for me and produced the behavior I've been looking for. Thank you! =^,^=

Comment: spacer did the trick thanks a ton

Answer (score 99):

You can do it in many ways.

Using **`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`**

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
);
```

---

Using **`Spacer`**

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    Spacer(),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
);
```

---

Using **`Expanded`**

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
);
```

---

Using **`Flexible`**

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    Flexible(fit: FlexFit.tight, child: SizedBox()),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
);
```

---

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I want one widget at the center and other to the extreme right. How can we achieve that ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy A good approach is to use `Stack` in that case.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy I am sure there must already be some question like this on SO, all you need to do is search with the right keyword. I can't really show you the code here in comment, but the idea is to use `Stack`, with its first child being `Align`(right) and second could be a `Center` or simple `Align`.

Answer (score 13):

Yes `CopsOnRoad` is right, through stack you can align one on right and other at center.

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Text("right"),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text("center"),
      )
    ],
  )
```

Comment: The default alignment is `Alignment.center` so you can omit that in your second `Align` widget.

Answer (score 5):

---

I had **multiple entries in my row**, and the accepted answer didn't work for me.
I needed to **wrap the final entry in an `Align`**.

---

I had :

```dart
Row( 
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    ...allMyLeftAlignedChildren,
    Expanded( 
      child: myRightAlignedChild,
```

And I needed :

```dart
Row( 
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    ...allMyLeftAlignedChildren,
    Expanded( 
      child: Align(                       // <---  these 2 lines fixed it 
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight, // <---  these 2 lines fixed it
        child: myRightAlignedChild,
```

Answer (score 4):

use the line of code `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` in a Row. That will allow The widgets to be on two extremes. However if you are working on TextField, use decoration class and the attribute prefix*** and suffix*** instead

Answer (score 4):

Using `Flexing` Widget

```
Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                '1',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              Flexible(fit: FlexFit.tight, child: SizedBox()),
              Text(
                '10',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```