# Flutter Row: align left and right, share remaining space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Here's an image of what I'd like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEkWT.png). Basically I want the left and right widgets to grow as much as possible until they'd both need to wrap, in which case each should take 50%. In most cases only one of the left or right widgets will be long enough to wrap - rarely both.

I've tried some of the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365770/flutter-align-two-items-on-extremes-one-on-the-left-and-one-on-the-right) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092977/is-it-possible-to-force-the-alignment-of-a-specific-child-widget-in-a-wrap-widge?rq=1) but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Did you try anything? If so show us for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListTile(
  title: Text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", maxLines: 2),
  trailing: Text("The quick brown", maxLines: 2),
);
```