# Flutter align two text widgets on extremes with a wrap

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, responsive

I would like to have two text widgets in a row, one on the left and one on the right. If the texts are too long there would be an overflow. To prevent this I want to display the right text in such a case one line below.

Here's what I'd like to have:
[image: with short texts on both sides]
[image: with long texts on both sides]

Here's what I've tried with `WrapAlignment.spaceBetween` and a `Wrap` widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Wrap(
    alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
    spacing: 16,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('a long text on the left side', textAlign: TextAlign.start),
      Text('a long text on the right side', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
    ],
  );
}
```

However, both texts stick to the left side:

[image: the result of my 1st attempt]

I have already tried to work with Align widgets, but it did not have the desired success. This is the code of my attempt:

```
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
  spacing: 16,
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft, child: Text('left side')),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight, child: Text('right side')),
  ],
)
```

However, this did not produce the desired result either:

[image: the result of my 2nd attempt]
Thank's in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try a `Column`, with 2 `Row` widgets, one with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` and the other `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but in this case both text fields will be displayed one below the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've found the solution here that works perfectly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092977/is-it-possible-to-force-the-alignment-of-a-specific-child-widget-in-a-wrap-widge)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LeftRightAlign(
    left: Text('left side',),
    right: Text('right side'),
  );
}
```

Here's the code for the custom `LeftRightAlign` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class LeftRightAlign extends MultiChildRenderObjectWidget {
  LeftRightAlign({
    Key key,
    @required Widget left,
    @required Widget right,
  }) : super(key: key, children: [left, right]);

  @override
  RenderLeftRightAlign createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderLeftRightAlign();
  }
}

class LeftRightAlignParentData extends ContainerBoxParentData<RenderBox> {}

class RenderLeftRightAlign extends RenderBox
    with
        ContainerRenderObjectMixin<RenderBox, LeftRightAlignParentData>,
        RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin<RenderBox, LeftRightAlignParentData> {

  RenderLeftRightAlign({
    List<RenderBox> children,
  }) {
    addAll(children);
  }

  @override
  void setupParentData(RenderBox child) {
    if (child.parentData is! LeftRightAlignParentData)
      child.parentData = LeftRightAlignParentData();
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    final BoxConstraints childConstraints = constraints.loosen();

    final RenderBox leftChild = firstChild;
    final RenderBox rightChild = lastChild;

    leftChild.layout(childConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);
    rightChild.layout(childConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);

    final LeftRightAlignParentData leftParentData = leftChild.parentData;
    final LeftRightAlignParentData rightParentData = rightChild.parentData;

    final bool wrapped =
        leftChild.size.width + rightChild.size.width > constraints.maxWidth;

    leftParentData.offset = Offset.zero;
    rightParentData.offset = Offset(
        constraints.maxWidth - rightChild.size.width,
        wrapped ? leftChild.size.height : 0);

    size = Size(
        constraints.maxWidth,
        wrapped
            ? leftChild.size.height + rightChild.size.height
            : math.max(leftChild.size.height, rightChild.size.height));
  }

  @override
  bool hitTestChildren(HitTestResult result, {Offset position}) {
    return defaultHitTestChildren(result, position: position);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    defaultPaint(context, offset);
  }
}
```

All credits to Jamens (: