# Flutter Wrap align and fill space

Tags: flutter

I want to use `Wrap` in flutter But I have some problem and confused!!

Consider the following widget layout

```
| A (100px width) | | B |
```

In a `Row` I have 2 widgets , if the width is not enough big it will overflow , So I replace `Row` with `Wrap`

```
<-------Available width------------->
| A (100px width) | | B |


<-Available width->
| A (100px width) |
| B |
```

#### 1. I want to have the following layout, How can I do this?

As you can see if we have enough space, `WrapAlignment.spaceBetween` works, otherwise the result is same as abovementioned! how can I have the following layout?

```
<-------Available width------------->
| A (100px width) |             | B |


<-Available width->
| A (100px width) |
              | B |
```

#### 2. What about the following layout?

Is it possible to force `B` widget to get full of width only it's in second `run`?

```
<-------Available width------------->
| A (100px width) |             | B |


<-Available width->
| A (100px width) |
|       B         |
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to achieve a type of responsiveness that exists in web with CSS media queries. You can do the same with MediaQueries in Flutter. But if you are trying to do this completely automatically just with Columns, Rows, Wrap and similar widgets, it is likely to be quite difficult. As you expect very different behaviours based on which row it's on.

Comment: What about the first question, I just want to align items

Comment: creating custom `Render` solve the first question. [Is it possible to force the alignment of a specific child widget in a Wrap widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55107333/13701072) check this out.