# flutter ListView - How do I align left and right at the same time?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, alignment

I have a ListView of items. I want to put a name on the left and a value on the right. unable to figure out a way to do this so that they're both aligned to the edge:

```
        ...
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Asset 0 <-  -> Balance',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.grey[850],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Asset 1 <-  -> Balance',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.grey[850],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Asset 2 <-  -> Balance',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.grey[850],
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
        ...
```

[image: aligned left]

(I want the balance on the right and the asset name on the left)

Is there, perhaps a special widget just for this purpose? I want it to be scrollable like a ListView and I want it to scroll together of course. It'd be cool if the row had an alignment option called edges that aligns two items in the row to each side respectively. but I don't think that exists. What's the common solution for this issue?

Comment: Use the row widget and align it's children using the cross axis alignment

Comment: I since found this, which might help others looking at this same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365770/flutter-align-two-items-on-extremes-one-on-the-left-and-one-on-the-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
row(
children:[
mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween;
Text(
              'Asset 0',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.grey[850],
              ),
            ),
Text(
              'Balance',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.grey[850],
              ),
            ),
]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to do the same when the `Row` is with multiple widgets is to add `Spacer()` between the `Row` `children`

**Sample Code**

```
Row(children: [
      Text(
        'Asset 0',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          color: Colors.grey[850],
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      Text(
        'Balance',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          color: Colors.grey[850],
        ),
      ),
    ])
```